# Google+ API: get user activities by date

Tags: php, api, symfony1, google-plus

My task is to get user list activities to the certain date, or from a certain date up to the current date. Does Google+ API have methods which can help to solve my task. Or can you tell me which way to look for?

I tried to get limited amount of activities

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'.$user->getGoogleId().'/activities/public?key='.sfConfig::get('app_google_plus_api_key')
            .'&maxResults='.sfConfig::get('app_google_plus_max_result'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP Bot');
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
```

then parse response and get necessary activities. But problem is that in this limited amount of activities may not contain necessary date because this activities are newer then that date. I'm sorry if I did not explain precisely enough. I'm not a native language speaker.

Comment: It is only small step from the Google+ API documentation to the Google search site. A very small one. I think if you combine the two, you will get exceptional results.

Comment: We don't care. Google yourself. Your question needs to contain the things you have tried, not what your task is.

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ API does not currently support this. Activities are returned from the `activities.list` method in the same order that they are displayed on https://plus.google.com. This means that while the first pages contain newer activities, older activities may be bumped up.

There is a [feature request for this](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=63) in the API's issue tracker. If you star the issue you will be notified when it is updated.